# Magento 2 how to build a reorder tool?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

[image]

Customer will get the search form to search order by **"order_id", "Date"**
Once the customer clicks on the search button then load all order which will match with the criteria.

Load the **"Re-order"** button with the search result 
Once the customer click on **"Re-Order"** button add to cart the product which is with the order.

I have added screenshot

[image]